# pg_restore fails with ERROR: could not create directory "pg_tblspc/16400/PG_11_201809051/16403": Invalid argument

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Trying to migrate PG9.1 data to PG11.5
I did initdb using the following command.

```
"<path>\bin\initdb.exe" --locale="English_Malaysia.1252" -D "<path>\pgupgrade" -U <user> --pwfile <path>

Command output: 
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "Administrator".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_Malaysia.1252".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "WIN1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
```

Part of pg_upgrade the following is failing:

```
command: "<bin_path>/pg_restore" --port 50432 --username <user> --create --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname template1 "pg_upgrade_dump_16388.custom" >> "pg_upgrade_dump_16388.log" 2>&1
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating DATABASE "xyz"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4037; 1262 16388 DATABASE xyz <user>
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not create directory "pg_tblspc/16400/PG_11_201809051/16403": Invalid argument
    Command was: CREATE DATABASE "xyz" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_Malaysia.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_Malaysia.1252' TABLESPACE = "xyz";
```

Can anyone tell me the possible cause of failure? Is it encoding issue? in first case DB was initialized with win1252 but during pg_restore it is running with utf8.
Also can you tell me how can I troubleshoot this error further as I am not getting what is "invalid argument" here?

Comment: That's a very strange error. Can you investigate if `pg_tblspc/16400/PG_11_201809051` exists? What is the operating system and file system used?

Comment: And don't upgrade to v11. Use at least v15.